# Style a input type=Number in React

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have an input type=Number field, which I am using in a React Project. I have used very simple styling and since I am very new and beginner to styling/CSS I am unable to make it look like this:

[image]

This is how it is looking right now:

[image]

I want the above input field using Styled Components/ any React based approach. I am using plain HTML and it is not looking like what I want. Help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

The following is what I have tried so far:
Main.tsx:

```
<input  value="1" type="number" min="1" max="10" />
```

The CSS: index.scss

```
input[type="number"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
    appearance: textfield;
}
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

I want to try out a Styled-Component way of usage, but couldn't think of any. Please guide me in doing so.

Comment: Please show us the code and styling that you have so far.

Comment: Yes sure, see the edited question.